# Is there a reason the Wachowskis chose the names Smith and Anderson?

Tags: the-matrix, names

The obvious reason and what I would assume is most likely is the frequency of these names in at least the United States:

```
Rank    Name     %
1.      Smith    1.006
2.      Johnson  0.810
3.      Williams 0.699
... 
11.     Anderson 0.311
```

Smith is the most common last name, meaning there would be a lot of them.  I had also assumed having similar names would make them more difficult to track in a hacker world.  Do any of these assumptions make sense?
Many movies shy away from using incredibly common last names, although I have no source for this.

Is there a reason the Wachowskis chose Smith and Anderson for the characters' names in *The Matrix*?

Comment: Are you asking why the program called "Smith" named himself Smith, or why the Wachowskis chose the name Smith for the character?

Comment: @JasonBaker why the Wachowskis chose the name Smith for the character?  Or the book writers if you must go back that far.

Comment: How can I make the question clearer?

Comment: As _Jason Baker_ says, if you change the title to clarify that "they" refers to "The Wachowski Sisters (Formerly The Wachowski Brothers)", it would be a bit clearer.

Comment: Also having the same question in your main body of text. Currently, the only question in the body is "Do any of these assumptions make sense?" Which isn't exactly a question that's answerable on this site, if at all.

Comment: "John Smith" is a slightly less common (in America) fake name after "John Doe." Google image "John Smith id card" ( https://www.google.com/search?q=%22john+smith%22+id+card&source=lnms&tbm=isch )

Comment: @Yorik source?  yes but individually they are the most common first names and last names.

Comment: I gave a source (the link). Here's another: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alias

Comment: @Yorik no source that John Smith is less common the John Doe.

Comment: William, @Yorik is at least partially correct; "John Doe" is *defined* in the New Oxford American Dictionary with a specialized North American Law definition as follows: "an anonymous party, typically the plaintiff, in a legal action."  Also: "(informal) a hypothetical average man."  By contrast, "John Smith" does not appear in the dictionary at all.  Now as to which name is *used* more often to *provide* a fake name where a real name is required, is a different question; but "John Doe" actually *means* "a hypothetical average man."

Comment: Do you know that great scene in “Die Hard” when agent Smith and special agent Smith are introduced?

Comment: I like how the percentile is 1 and 0, after all, the matrix is just 1's and 0's

Comment: @Wildcard: "John Smith" appears in the dictionary under "alias"

Comment: @Wildcard: you can start with my link to one above. I found 3 different ones that use John Smith in their example of an alias. I will leave it to you to re-find all the examples of John Smith as *the prototype* common alias using Google Books and a very simple 4-word search.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You might find [this page](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/cyberpunk/matrix_spirit.shtml) useful. It details even vague connections, themes and references that each name in *The Matrix* has, including some for *Thomas A. Anderson*, those mainly being:

- *Thomas* means "Twin", in reference to the fact that he's been "living two lives", one as Thomas and the other as Neo.
- *Thomas* is also the name of one of Jesus' disciples, namely "Doubting Thomas", who did not believe Jesus had died and been resurrected until he saw the holes in Jesus' hands, much like Thomas A. Anderson never believed he was the One until he himself died and came back to life after being shot full of holes.
- *Anderson* means "Son of Man", in keeping with the whole "Messiah" theme that goes on throughout the trilogy (I mean movie, just one movie, there's only one movie).

As for the Agents, the whole point about them is that they have common, boring anglo-saxon surnames, such as Smith, Jones, Brown, etc.
You might find that one of the reasons they picked Anderson as a surname for Neo was simply because they'd used up a bunch of other common names for Agents and Anderson was simply next on the list. Neo's exact surname may not ultimately be all that important, though I have to say hearing Smith call him "Mr. Anderson" is a nice touch that probably wouldn't have worked with many other surnames.

Comment: I have always loved the way Hugo Weaving drawls Anderson, i.e. "Mister Annnnderson".

Comment: @BinaryWorrier also how he says "Mordor" in LotR (as Elrond) : Mor-r-r-dor-r-r

Comment: I dunno if they picked the common names on purpose but it's pretty effective at driving home the idea that anyone could "turn into" an Agent at any time, and that they're "all the same," as Morpheus puts it.

Comment: Now imagine Elrond giving the ["virus" speech to Frodo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IM1-DQ2Wo_w). *"...I realized that you're not actually mammals. Every mammal on this planet instinctively develops a natural equilibrium... but you hobbits do not. You move to an area and you multiply and multiply until every natural resource is consumed and the only way you can survive is to spread to another area. There is another organism on this planet that follows the same pattern. Do you know what it is? A virus. Hobbits are a disease, a cancer of this planet. You're a plague and we are the cure."*

Comment: @Schwern, but are there viruses in Middle Earth, even in Elvish lore?

Comment: @Schwern "[Welcome to Rivendell… Mr. Anderson.](https://youtu.be/lJN4u9rZVjw)"

Comment: @BinaryWorrier "Mister Arrrrragorn...  Welcome back.  We... missed you."

Comment: aNdErsOn, spells Neo in the right order, it has Neo hidden right in there. THomas andEsON, hads all the letters needed for "The One" (albeit out of order). Neo is an anagram of One as well. Might be coincidence, but I doubt it.

Comment: A can't ever talk to someone named, or hear the name, Anderson without hearing it in Hug Weaving's voice.

Comment: I don't think that this had anything to do with the choice but ``anders`` is the German word for ``different``.

Answer (score 58):

I'm unclear whether it's a case of the tail wagging the dog, but it's notable that Agent Smith's car (in Matrix Reloaded) has the plate ***IS5416*** ([Isiah 54:16](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Isaiah_54:16))

> *"Behold, I have created the smith who blows the fire of coals, and produces a weapon for its purpose. I have also created the ravager to
>   destroy..."*

This seems a pretty solid description of Agent Smith's role in the world of the Matrix and would explain the choice of name.

[image]

That being said, it's certainly possible that having created a character called Smith, that the Wachowskis then went looking for biblical reference that had the word "smith" in and got lucky.

Comment: Why would agents even use cars? Although I suppose constantly jumping around and taking over nodes in the matrix might cause instability in the system. Still, it seems redundant.

Comment: @Withywindle - So that they can transport prisoners.

Comment: @Withywindle [In answering "Why are there only three Agents at a time in the Matrix?"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/81049/1441) I supposed that Agents are disruptive and used sparingly. The Matrix is an illusion for the benefit of the humans trapped inside it. Agents doing super-human feats and taking people over risks whole point of the Matrix. Instead, they'd prefer to act as part of the Matrix taking on the plausible shadowy government "Men In Black" role which means driving a car. They'd use their powers when they decide it's worth stopping an even greater disruption.

Comment: I would agree with this answer but I tend to think now a days that agent Smith is the chosen one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkMU1mKdwPI

Comment: @Schwern: that’s a founded assumption. Recall, at the beginning of first movie, they only take over other people when there are no witnesses around (members of the resistance don’t count). At the end, after Neo has proven how dangerous he is (he managed to *win* a fight against an agent), they don’t care anymore, jumping around mindlessly.

Comment: @schwern - Have you ever woken up and realised it's not Wednesday, it's actually Thursday and can't for the life of you remember what you did yesterday? That's because you spent the day being an Agent. There's quite a lot of people out there (especially those that work from home) that wouldn't even notice they'd lost a day

Comment: @Holger it does seem that as the amount of node-jumping increased the stability of the Matrix became an issue. However, Matrix instability is expected as part of the runtime - hence the purpose of the One. Smith, although, is an unknown variable and the effects are quite destructive. I suppose the question is if the node-jumping introduces instability with increased frequency, or if there is a limit of jumped nodes that, when reached, causes some kind of exception (out of memory?).

Comment: If it's a biblical reference in relation to The Matrix, it's almost certainly valid.

Comment: @Valorum `There's quite a lot of people out there (especially those that work from home) that wouldn't even notice they'd lost a day` If they have a remote job (which would be most people who work *"from home"* as opposed to *"at home"*), they will notice when they see a bunch of emails from their bosses asking where they are :P

Comment: @xDaizu - Assuming you have a boss, obviously.